How to external css code work for html code in same file
I am currently workingon my School HTML and CSS code that I have experienced before, however even I tried various method such as copying teacher's example or refer to my past project, my CSS code doesn't work at my HTML, Do you know how to fix this?
(My past CSS code and HTML code works normally)
HTML code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Webstyle.css">
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Webpage Example</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div><img src="Myself.jpg" alt="Arata" height="300" class="center"> ##Align to the right</div>

    <br>

    <div>
        <p>・Self Introduction</p>
        <p>・My work</p>
        <p>・Contact</p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h1>Self Introduction</h1>
        <p> My Name : ○○</p>
        <p>My nationality : ○○</p>
        <p>My age : ○○</p>
        <p>Current job : ○○</p>
        <p>Skill : Drawing</p>
        <p>Hobby : Vudeo recordings, Video games</p>
        <p>Favourite food :Fried food</p>
    </div>

    
</body>
</html>

CSS code
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

#header{
    background-colour : black;
    color : white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}

The CSS code should works normally to make the title of webpage as black background in white text and aligned in center. I tried to fix my refering to my past work.

"It doesn't work" is not a problem description: what do you see it do? Just looking at what you posted, background-colour is not a CSS property, it's background-color, so that rule does nothing, and color: white means you're setting white text on an almost certainly white background. So: use the browser's developer tools to see what's really happening. Inspect your document, look at what CSS is applied (or isn't, and why), and look for errors/warnings in the console. Also: don't put elements between </head> and <body>: that link element should go in the head.


Changed background-colour to background-color in css file.

Moved the <link> tag inside the <head> section.


Example:
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Webstyle.css">
</head>

Note: Ensure the Webstyle.css file is in the same directory as your HTML file, or adjust the href attribute in the <link> tag accordingly.

The link element needs to be moved inside your head tag.

You can check these things below:

Make sure webstyle.css and your html file are in the same folder.
Better not to use text in uppercase for file name. Webstyle.css (no), the right way would be webstyle.css (yes). It doesn't affect much but still.
background-colour (no), it should either be only background:black; or background-color:black; (yes)
Always link style files in the <head></head> section after the meta tags.

Try above and check again!
See below image for naming the files:

